# How to vertical align middle (content) when table td div height is fixed?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

I am having one table and some table rows. I want to fix height for the td so I created one div setting height to 60px and overflow to hidden which give me the appropriate output. But if the content is less in td it should be vertically aligned to middle.

```css
table, th, td {
  border:1px solid black;
}
.fixed-height{
    height:60px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:50%">
  <tr>
   <td><div class="fixed-height" ><span>TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST
   TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST EST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TE
   </span>
   </div></td>
    <td>Tobias</td>
    <td>Linus</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><div class="fixed-height" >this should be center</div></td>
    <td>Tobias</td>
    <td>Linus</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="fixed-height" >this should be centerl</div></td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/amansadhwani/61fLdjps)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your css.

```
.fixed-height {
  display: inline-grid;
  align-items: center;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This works fine when when there are two or multiple spans in div it occupies more space.[screenshot](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Capture_29.png)

Comment: or else you can specify another class for vertical alignment. `You can use display: flex, align-items: center`. Hope it helps :-)

Comment: Earlier I tried with flex itself but for some reason the text is cutting down  [ss](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Capture_49.png)

Comment: Yes thats why I mentioned you need a specify a new class. If this going to be a static page this will solve the issue. If it is dynamic, this approach not be the best..

Comment: It would be dynamic would look for another sol'n